# Load UIImage to float array for DeepLearningKit usage

Tags: ios, swift, deep-learning, caffe

I'd like to use the [DeepLearningKit](https://github.com/DeepLearningKit/DeepLearningKit) for iOS. I want to use UIImage objects to be classified. The sample application only uses a float array loaded from a json file. Thus I have to create the bitmap representation of the UIImage as a float array and use this for the classify-method.

Can anybody help me on that? Is there a way to create a bitmap representation for UIImage? Moreover I have to swap the channels from RGB to BGR.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added an extension to UIImage that allows setting and getting RGB(A) pixels directly - key methods:

```
public func setPixelColorAtPoint(point:CGPoint, color: RawColorType) -> UIImage? 
func getPixelColorAtLocation(point:CGPoint)->UIColor?
```

where RawColorType is defined as

```
public typealias RawColorType = (newRedColor:UInt8, newgreenColor:UInt8, newblueColor:UInt8,  newalphaValue:UInt8)
```

This way you should be able to convert back and forth between bitmap representation and UIImage. Wrote a blog post that gives some more context: http://deeplearningkit.org/tutorials-for-ios-os-x-and-tvos/tutorial-image-handling-in-deeplearningkit/

Comment: Downvoted as link no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I've write a function to convert a image file to Caffe blob on iOS platform. You can find it [here](https://github.com/solrex/caffe-mobile/blob/master/examples/ios/simple/CaffeSimple/ImageReader.mm). I hope it will help you.

Code snippet:

```
// Convert Bitmap (channels*width*height) to Matrix (width*height*channels)
// Remove alpha channel
int input_channels = input_layer->channels();
LOG(INFO) << "image_channels:" << image_channels << " input_channels:" << input_channels;
if (input_channels == 3 && image_channels != 4) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "image_channels input_channels not match.";
    return false;
} else if (input_channels == 1 && image_channels != 1) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "image_channels input_channels not match.";
    return false;
}

float *input_data = input_layer->mutable_cpu_data();

for (size_t h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    for (size_t w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < input_channels; c++) {
            // OpenCV use BGR instead of RGB
            size_t cc = c;
            if (input_channels == 3) {
                cc = 2 - c;
            }
            // Convert uint8_t to float
            input_data[c*width*height + h*width + w] = 
                static_cast<float>(result[h*width*image_channels + w*image_channels + cc]);
            if (mean.size() == input_channels) {
                input_data[c*width*height + h*width + w] -= mean[c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged "Swift", though... not "Objective-C++". :)